# Como fazer o método join() funcionar para cada palavra de várias listas dentro de uma outra lista

Tags: python, lista

Eu tinha feito algo assim para a lista pares e impares
pois a questão pede:

- que leia várias palavras (uma por uma)
- e concatene em dois (2) textos as palavras lidas, conforme a saber:
- ✓ TEXTO 1: Todas as Palavras de Tamanho PAR;
- ✓ TEXTO 2: Todas as Palavras de Tamanho ÍMPAR;
- ✓ Concatene também um hífen: ‘-’ entre cada palavra do TEXTO 1 e 2.

---

```
par = []
impar = []
a = ""
b = ""
while True:
    print('---MENU---')
    print('1- Palavra PAR / 2 - Palavra IMPAR/ 0 - SAIR')
    opcao = int(input())
    if opcao == 1:
        print('Digite uma palavra de tamanho PAR: ')
        palavra = (input())
        pal = palavra
        par.append(palavra)
    if opcao == 2:
        print('Digite uma palavra de tamanho IMPAR: ')
        palavra2 = input()
        pa = palavra2
        impar.append(palavra2)
    if opcao == 0:
        break

for i in range(len(par)):
    for j in range(i):
        for x in par[i][j]:
            a = '-'.join(par)

for r in range (len(impar)):
    for l in range(r):
        for z in par[r][l]:
            b ='-'.join(impar)

#printar resultados para usuário:
print(a)
print(b)
```

Mas ele só printava algo como

> 'abcd-acbd' caso tenha duas palavras pares e não: a-b-c-d, a-c-b-d

Comment: Poderia colocar exemplos de quais serão as entradas do seu programa e colocar quais deveriam ser as saídas produzidas, explicando o contexto? Só com o que colocou na pergunta ficou impossível de entender o problema. Busque elaborar um [mcve] para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Eu editei, melhorou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está nos seus dois últimos *for loops*. É possível fazer o que você quer alterando os loops, utilizando listas de listas e o método `insert` de listas. Veja:

```
par = []
impar = []
a = ""
b = ""
while True:
    print('---MENU---')
    print('1- Palavra PAR / 2 - Palavra IMPAR/ 0 - SAIR')
    opcao = int(input())
    if opcao == 1:
        print('Digite uma palavra de tamanho PAR: ')
        palavra = (input())
        pal = palavra
        par.append(palavra)
    if opcao == 2:
        print('Digite uma palavra de tamanho IMPAR: ')
        palavra2 = input()
        pa = palavra2
        impar.append(palavra2)
    if opcao == 0:
        break

lista_words_par = [] #essa será a lista de listas (a primeira dimensão é palavra e a segunda dimensão á letra)
par_split =[] #essa á a lista de sublistas (contendo as letras de cada palavra)
for word in par:
    for j in word:
        par_split.append(j)
    lista_words_par.insert(par.index(word),par_split) #inserindo a lista de letras que formam a palavra. Note que usamos o index da palavra na ordem que foi inserida pelo usuário na lista par
    par_split = [] #zera a lista de letras da palavra para usá-la novamente na próxima palavra

lista_words_impar = []
par_split =[]
for word in impar:
    for j in word:
        par_split.append(j)
    lista_words_impar.insert(impar.index(word),par_split)
    par_split = []

print('Palavras pares')
for i in lista_words_par:
    print('-'.join(i))

print('Palavras ímpares')
for i in lista_words_impar:
    print('-'.join(i))
```

Ver comentários no código para maior detalhamento de como o *for loop* foi feito

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado, eu aprendi coisas novas com o que você fez, mas o que eu queria era:
Concatene também um hífen: ‘-’ entre cada palavra do TEXTO 1 e 2.
Ou seja, para cada palavra par(2,4,6...) letras, botar um hífen entre elas, por exemplo: amigos -> a-m-i-g-o-s

Comment: para fazer isso basta usar  o `'-'join(i)` em cada print. Vou editar o código para incluir isso

Comment: Ah, foi mal, eu tentei fazer isso, mas provavelmente coloquei o join no lugar errado, mas obrigado mesmo

Comment: Mais uma dúvida, usou o insert ao invés do append por que? não sei se entendi bem o comentário, mas diz que é pra ficar em ordem? não já fica em ordem automaticamente?

Comment: Realmente, no seu caso não faz diferença. A vantagem do `insert`é só controlar a ordem mesmo